# How to clean up dodgy JSON file from server

Tags: jquery, json

I'm trying to use a JSON feed from our site, which unfortately is not formated correctly. I can clean up the feed via calling it first via the `$.ajax` call, but want to be able to pass this cleaned up content back to iterate over as if it was a JSON object.

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    // use ajax call as json supplied needs cleaning first
    $.ajax({
        url: 'JSON.txt',
        success: function (data)
        {
            var i = 0;
            var html = '';
            var regex = /<!--.+?-->/g;
            responseText = data.replace(regex,'');  // clean up Jahia's dodgy JSON output
            $('body').append(responseText);
        }
    });
});
```

Any ideas how to return the responseText back as a JSON object so that I can use the $.each function to parse the file?

Answer (score 1):

Since you're already using jquery, use [jQuery.parseJSON()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/) to convert the string to a JSON object.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the json library to convert a text string to a json object.

Library:
https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js

Documentation:
http://www.json.org/js.html

Comment: Per his description, the JSON Object is not valid as sent back by the Server.  He has to modify the string representation before it will parse as an object.

Comment: Yep, misread the question. I've now removed that chunk of misinformation :)

Answer (score 0):

You can't really return anything from the body of most AJAX callback functions because they're asynchronous.  Once you've formatted the JSON String you can turn it into a JSON Object by eval'ing it (technically bad practice, but it's how you can turn a string into an object), and then passing it to another function as a parameter.  So something like this:

```
var newJSON = eval(responseText);
handleJSON(newJSON);
```

Where handleJSON would have to be a function you defined elsewhere in the code that knew how to process the responses you'll receive.